# Getting user data based on message

Tags: android, firebase, mvp

I'm developing a chat application with the MVP archeciture and I want to display the profile picture (avatar) of the user sending a message like regular chat applications, but I don't know how to access the "users" node based on the sender of a message. My database structure looks like this:

[image]

I retrieve messages like this:

Interactor:

```
@Override
public void getChatRoomMessages(String uid) {
    mMessageReference.child(uid).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            mMessage = dataSnapshot.getValue(Message.class);
            mMessagePresenter.showMessages(mMessage);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }
       ...
}
```

My adapter class:

```
public class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.MessageViewHolder> {

private List<Message> mMessages = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MessageAdapter.MessageViewHolder holder, int position) {

    //set avatar of user
    Message msg = mMessages.get(position);
    int userid = msg.getSender();
    //use userid to query user node 

}

public void addMessages(Message message) {
    mMessages.add(message);
    notifyItemChanged(mMessages.size() - 1);
}
```

I need to query the user node based on the userid of the "sender", but with the MVP approach I cannot do this in the adapter class. Where and how can I query the user node using the userid from "sender"?

Comment: How is `mMessageReference` defined?

Comment: Like this: `mMessageReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("messages");
`

Comment: `iASD ... 3232` is the id of the user?

Comment: No, `iMcYqQzV16..` is the userid

Comment: What is the value of `uid` in `.child(uid)`, `iMcYqQzV16`?

Comment: The value is the userid of the user.

Comment: And to undestand better, you want to get all messages based on uid, for instance  `iMcYqQzV16` and get the name of the user, right?

Comment: No, I want to get the `imageUri` from the `user` node based on the value of `sender` in the `messages` node.

Comment: So you want to get **all** messages based on `uid`, for instance `iMcYqQzV16` and get the image url of the user, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195472/discussion-between-john-and-alex-mamo).

Comment: Please leave a comment with the complete explanation.